# Only load layout when firebase calls are complete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem: the layout in my MainActivity is generated before I have a chance to finish calling the firebase to restore app data. If I rotate the screen, thus causing onCreate to run again in the MainActivity, everything is generated just fine.

In my app, I have a custom implementation of the Application class, which makes a bunch of calls to Firebase in order to restore data / make sure data is always in sync. However, instead of having just a few ValueEventListeners with a ton of children underneath, I have around 20 ValueEventListeners. This is to prevent my app from syncing nearly the entire database every time the user generates a tiny bit of data, and to avoid conflicts that can happen when data is manipulated asynchronously. Interestingly, the ValueEventListeners don't actually fetch their data in the order that they're coded in, so I can't set a bool to true when the last one is done.

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to detect whether the firebase reads are all done, other than placing some code at the end of every single Listener and performing an operation that does this manually. I've looked at the methods available in the Application class, as well as Firebase, and so far I haven't found anything that works.

some code from my Application class:

```
public class CompassApp extends Application {
```

... then inside the Application's onCreate:

```
//        Fetching Data from DB.
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference();

//        Current User Data
    dbRef.child("currentAppData").child("workingOut").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            activeFirebaseConnections += 1;
//                Stops executing method if there is no data to retrieve
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                return;
            }

            workingOut = dataSnapshot.getValue(boolean.class);

            activeFirebaseConnections -= 1;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Firebase read of sleepDebt failed");
        }
    });
    dbRef.child("currentAppData").child("sleeping").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            activeFirebaseConnections += 1;
//                Stops executing method if there is no data to retrieve
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                return;
            }

            sleeping = dataSnapshot.getValue(boolean.class);

            activeFirebaseConnections -= 1;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Firebase read of sleepDebt failed");
        }
    });
```

(and so on... the rest is just more ValueEventListeners)

Comment: Instead of describing your code, can you post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem]http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added a snippet from the Application class. The code that actually inflates the layout uses a couple very specific libraries and because it passes through some very unique application logic it can be more confusing than anything. 

What's important is that according to the debugger and the logs, the ValueEventListeners are running AFTER the methods that inflate the layout (in MainActivity's onCreate) are. So the layouts are always inflated with default data when the app loads for the first time.

Comment: I also previously tried an implementation where the firebase calls were made in the Activity onCreate itself, and though it worked 100% of the time, there was a very noticeable lag in the UI generation.

Answer (score 16):

I'm currently using a utility class that I created for kicking off multiple loads of data.  It will trigger a final Task when all of the listeners are complete.  They key here is clever use of the new [Task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) facility for asynchronous programming provided by Play Services.  You could probably do all this using some other async framework, but Tasks come for free with Play Services and are used in other parts of Firebase, so you may as well learn to use them.  :-)

I gave a talk at Google I/O 2016 about tasks.  Here is [a link to a video](https://youtu.be/AJqakuas_6g?t=6m27s) that jumps directly to the relevant part of that session.

```
public class FirebaseMultiQuery {

    private final HashSet<DatabaseReference> refs = new HashSet<>();
    private final HashMap<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot> snaps = new HashMap<>();
    private final HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    public FirebaseMultiQuery(final DatabaseReference... refs) {
        for (final DatabaseReference ref : refs) {
            add(ref);
        }
    }

    public void add(final DatabaseReference ref) {
        refs.add(ref);
    }

    public Task<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> start() {
        // Create a Task<DataSnapsot> to trigger in response to each database listener.
        //
        final ArrayList<Task<DataSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(refs.size());
        for (final DatabaseReference ref : refs) {
            final TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> source = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
            final ValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener(ref, source);
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
            listeners.put(ref, listener);
            tasks.add(source.getTask());
        }

        // Return a single Task that triggers when all queries are complete.  It contains
        // a map of all original DatabaseReferences originally given here to their resulting
        // DataSnapshot.
        //
        return Tasks.whenAll(tasks).continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                task.getResult();
                return new HashMap<>(snaps);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        for (final Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : listeners.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().removeEventListener(entry.getValue());
        }
        snaps.clear();
        listeners.clear();
    }

    private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
        private final DatabaseReference ref;
        private final TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskSource;

        public MyValueEventListener(DatabaseReference ref, TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskSource) {
            this.ref = ref;
            this.taskSource = taskSource;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            snaps.put(ref, dataSnapshot);
            taskSource.setResult(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            taskSource.setException(databaseError.toException());
        }
    }

}
```

The way you use it is like this.  Determine all the `DatabaseReference`s you need to load data from and store them in members of your Activity.  Then, during your activity `onStart()`, pass them all into an instance of FirebaseMultiQuery and call `start()` on it. It will return a Task that generates a Map of DatabaseReference to the DataSnapshot it will generate.  With that Task in hand, register a final listener that will trigger when all the data is loaded:

```
firebaseMultiQuery = new FirebaseMultiQuery(dbRef1, dbRef2, dbRef3, ...);
final Task<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> allLoad = firebaseMultiQuery.start();
allLoad.addOnCompleteListener(activity, new AllOnCompleteListener());
```

And in your `onStop()`, don't forget to call `stop()` on it to make sure everything is shut down properly:

```
firebaseMultiQuery.stop();
```

The listener triggered by the completion of the task that receives all the data in a map can look something like this:

```
private class AllOnCompleteListener implements OnCompleteListener<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            final Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot> result = task.getResult();
            // Look up DataSnapshot objects using the same DatabaseReferences you passed into FirebaseMultiQuery
        }
        else {
            exception = task.getException();
            // log the error or whatever you need to do
        }
        // Do stuff with views
        updateUi();
    }
}
```

It's perhaps worth noting that Firebase Database calls that write data also return Tasks that you can listen on for completion.  Also, Firebase Storage uses Tasks, and so does Firebase Authentication.

The code here may not currently work with a Firebase Database Query that is not a simple named reference into a node in your database.  It depends on whether they are hashed in a way that's consistent for keying into a HashMap.

The code above is still somewhat experimental, but I haven't had any problems with it so far.  It seems like a lot of code, but if you do a lot of concurrent loading, it's really handy.

Comment: thanks :) this looks promising, but also quite a bit more complex than I was expecting. I'm going to have to take some time to go over this...

Comment: This seems great to me.. Is there any blog post about it with detailed explanation of the Tasks API? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks is not just enough..

Comment: @kirtan403 I spoke about it in some detail at I/O '16.  You can watch that here (jumps directly to the part about Tasks).  https://youtu.be/AJqakuas_6g?t=6m28s  Should do a blog too....

Comment: I have already watched it more than 3 times. But sometimes written explained examples do the trick. A blog post will be helpful for the newbies on firebase and async tasks like me

Comment: Anyone considering using this approach would benefit from reading Doug's  very complete and detailed [series of blog posts on Tasks](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).

Comment: I love your logic. Thank you!

Comment: How to catch a situation when nothing is completed because Internet is absent? I don't catch it in neither addOnFailureListener, addOnCanceledListener or addOnCompleteListener. And how to get data from Firebase cache then? Thanks.

Comment: @DougStevenson But I noted that you are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. So, how can we observe the changes in data this way? This seems like a one time fetch operation.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem with my app. After a long research on how to check if firebase is done retrieving data, I found this solution.

So when you have multiple event listeners in your app. Firebase doesn't execute this listeners one by one in sequence. 
The Value Event Listener is always executed at last. 
So if you want to execute something when all the data is retrieved, you can call a ValueEventListener and execute a method which loads all your views inside it.

So use `rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and inside its `onDataChanged()` execute what you want to execute after data is retrieved from Firebase.

This worked for me, Hope it works for you too

Comment: The problem is that I have 20 ValueEventListeners, so they just run in a seemingly random order. I need to know when all of them are done running. I suppose I could increment an int in every single one, and I would know that when my int = the number of listeners that I have, then it would be done. That feels more like a workaround than a solution

Comment: have you tried logging? to check the pattern on how `ValueEventListeners` are executed?  Also try to implement the logic for what you want to execute after data is retrieved from Firebase in the last `ValueEventListener`

Comment: It seems to respect some kind of order, but there doesn't seem to be much logic behind it. I thought about that, but there's a good chance that I'll be adding more listeners as my app's data set expands, and I don't want my code to break each time... That being said it could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Doug Stevenson answer is great. Almost worked out of the box for me. The only thing I changed was instead of creating a  AllOnCompleteListener class explicitly, I wrote the code like below:

```
    private OnCompleteListener<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> allListener;...



allListener = new OnCompleteListener<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot>> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          final Map<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot> result = task.getResult();
          // Look up DataSnapshot objects using the same DatabaseReferences you passed into FirebaseMultiQuery



          for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, DataSnapshot> entry : result.entrySet()) { ...}
```