# Android: wait for firebase valueEventListener

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, semaphore

I am trying to use Semaphore to wait for my firebase valueEventListener. I have an user info activity with 6 different fields that the user must fill out. When the user saves his/her info, I  want to do an "all or nothing" type of check. Certain user info cannot be duplicated...for example user name, email, and phonenumber. I am using firebase and currently the general idea is of the format:

```
void saveUserInfo(){
    if(field1 exist in database){
        return;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    if(field6 exist in database){
        return;
    }

    savefield1();
    .
    .
    .
    savefield6();
}
```

The issue I am having is in the method that checks whether or not the value already exists in the database. Here is my current method:

```
   public boolean alreadyInUse(String key, String value) throws InterruptedException {

    final StringBuilder done = new StringBuilder("");
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

    mDatabase.child(key).child(value).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String result = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if(result == null){
                Log.d("WorkoutLog", "result: null");
                done.append("false");
                semaphore.release();
                return;
            }
            else if(result.equals(uID)){
                Log.d("WorkoutLog", "result: " + result.toString());
                done.append("false");
                semaphore.release();
                return;
            }
            else{
                Log.d("WorkoutLog", "result: " + result.toString());
                done.append("true");
                semaphore.release();
                return;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    semaphore.acquire();
    if(done.equals("true")){
        return  true;
    }
    else if(done.equals("false")){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        Log.d("WorkoutLog", "Shouldn't be here");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Right now the semaphore is not releasing...Was wondering if anyone can help me out here. Without the semaphore, the return statement will fire before the firebase query can complete...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The listener callback methods run on the main thread.  If you call `alreadyInUse()` on the main thread, it will block the thread at `semaphore.acquire()`, preventing the callbacks from running and releasing the semaphore.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete/38188683#38188683) to a related question helpful.

Answer (score 13):

As previously mentioned, you can use [Firebase Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/package-summary) presented on [Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJqakuas_6g).

```
Task<?>[] tasks = new Task[] {
    saveUserName(username),
    saveFriends(friends),
    saveOtherStuff(stuff)
};

Tasks.whenAll(tasks)
    .continueWithTask(new RollbackIfFailure())
    .addOnCompleteListener(this)
    .addOnFailureListener(this);
```

If each step that makes a modification can run in parallel, you can create a method that returns a [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) for each one of them as follows:

```
public Task<String> saveUserName(final String username) {
    final TaskCompletionSource<String> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

    mDatabase.child("users")
        .child(username)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String username = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (null == username) {
                tcs.setResult(null);
            } else {
                tcs.setException(new IllegalStateException(username));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            tcs.setException(new IOException(TAG, firebaseError.toException()));
        }
    });

    return tcs.getTask();
}
```

If any of them fail, you need to rollback the operations. Since this can be threated by a single task, you can create a [`Continuation`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Continuation) task:

```
class RollbackIfFailure implements Continuation<Void, Task<Void>> {
    @Override
    public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {

        final TaskCompletionSource<Void> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            tcs.setResult(null);
        } else {
            // Rollback everything
        }

        return tcs.getTask();
    }
}
```