# Promise in Android, how to implement?

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the easiest way to implement the same behaviour on Android? I mean I would like to have my thread (not main) wait for network operations and execute them one after another. In javascript, there is simple way to implement this behaviour thanks to Promise.

```
   exports.someFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        const userId = req.query.user
        //long time
        ref.orderByChild("parentId").equalTo(userId)
            .on("value", function (snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.val() === null) {
                    res.status(402)
                    return
                }
                snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                    const foo = childSnapshot.val();
                        getAccessToken().then(fistResponse => {

                            var json = JSON.parse(fistResponse);
                            accToken = json.access_token;

                            getMoreInformation(accToken, foo.bar).then(response => {
                                console.log(response)
                                if (isValid(response)) {
                                    res.status(200) 
                                } else {
                                    res.status(402)
                                }
                            })})})})});
```

Currently I am using interface, but I would like to learn other way.

**I found there is something like [Future](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) in android and that is probably what I am looking for.**

Comment: There is no wait operation in java, you need to use an interface

Comment: what about [Future](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) I have mentioned. Haven't tried it yet, but I'll be back with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you'd use `Task`s for that. In fact, most of the Firebase Android SDK returns `Task`s, but unfortunately the Firebase Database API predates that and works with its own `ValueEventListener` class.

Firebase's Doug Stevenson is a master at `Task`s and has:

- Given a [talk about `Task`s in Firebase at I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/AJqakuas_6g?t=6m27s).
- Written a [series of blog posts about `Task`s in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).
- Gave an answer to an [extremely similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete/38188683#38188683) that maps the Firebase listeners to tasks, so that you can use `Tasks.whenAll(...)` (the equivalent of `Promise.all(...)` to wait until all items are loaded.